# Solve $\cos 5x + \sin \frac{5x}{2} = 1$ for $x \in [0, \pi]$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I have to solve the equation:

$$\cos 5x + \sin \dfrac{5x}{2} = 1$$

with $x \in [0, \pi]$.

Using the formula:

$$\sin x = \sqrt{\dfrac{1 - \cos 2x}{2}}$$

I found that:

$$\sin \dfrac{5x}{2} = \sqrt{\dfrac{1 - \cos 5x}{2}}$$

So the equation becomes:

$$\cos 5x + \sqrt{\dfrac{1 - \cos 5x}{2}} = 1$$

Here I used the notation $t = \cos 5x$, with $t \in [-1, 1]$. The equation is then:

$$t + \sqrt{\dfrac{1-t}{2}} = 1$$

After subtracting a $t$ and squaring the equation we get the quadratic:

$$2t^2 - 3t + 1 = 0$$

with the solutions:

$$t_1 = 1 \hspace{3cm} t_2 = \dfrac{1}{2}$$

and both solutions are in the interval $[-1, 1]$.

Solving for the first case we get:

$$\cos 5x = 1$$

$$5x = 0 + 2k \pi$$

$$x = \dfrac{2k \pi}{5}$$

with $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Because we have that $x \in [0, \pi]$, we get the solutions:

$$x \in \bigg \{ 0, \dfrac{2 \pi}{5}, \dfrac{4 \pi}{5} \bigg \}$$

Solving for the second case we get:

$$\cos 5x = \dfrac{1}{2}$$

$$5x = \dfrac{\pi}{3} + 2k \pi \hspace{2cm} 5x = - \dfrac{\pi}{3} + 2k \pi$$

$$x = \dfrac{\pi + 6k \pi}{15} \hspace{2cm} x = \dfrac{-\pi + 6k \pi}{15}$$

knowing that $x \in [0, \pi]$ we get:

$$x \in \bigg \{ \dfrac{\pi}{15}, \dfrac{7 \pi}{15}, \dfrac{13 \pi}{15} \bigg \} \hspace{2cm} x \in \bigg \{ \dfrac{5 \pi}{15}, \dfrac{11 \pi}{15} \bigg \}$$

Now combining the solutions for the first and second case we get the full solution of:

$$x \in \bigg \{ 0, \dfrac{\pi}{15}, \dfrac{\pi}{3}, \dfrac{2\pi}{5}, \dfrac{7 \pi}{15}, \dfrac{11 \pi}{15}, \dfrac{4 \pi}{5}, \dfrac{13 \pi}{15} \bigg \}$$

The problem here is that this is not right. The solution given by my textbook is actually:

$$x \in \bigg \{ 0, \dfrac{\pi}{15}, \dfrac{\pi}{3}, \dfrac{2\pi}{5}, \dfrac{4 \pi}{5}, \dfrac{13 \pi}{15} \bigg \}$$

So the same solution, but without $\dfrac{7 \pi}{15}$ and $\dfrac{11 \pi}{15}$. And this is actually right, I checked it on the original equation and the equation does not equal $1$ if $x = \dfrac{7 \pi}{15}$ or if $x = \dfrac{11 \pi}{15}$. But I don't see my mistake. What did I do wrong that resulted in me getting $2$ extra solutions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Squaring can give you an extra "solutions" which are actually not.

Better put $y=5x/2$ and solve  $$\cos 2y+\sin y=1$$

which is equivalent to $$ 2\sin^2y -\sin y =0$$

Comment: (+1) but I have a question I see lots of answers on the site that people skip some levels of problem solving for example here you skipped ($1-2sin^2y+siny=1$) I want know you or other mathematicians do this to avoid long and confusing answer on site or you do these calculations by mind always and write like this in exams and other places? Thanks